# Maximum distance between two points on shape - name?

Tags: geometry, definition

What is the name for the maximum distance between two points lying on a geometric shape? For the circle, such a thing is obviously called "the diameter". Is it called "the diameter" for every other arbitrary shape as well?

Comment: Yes: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diameter#Generalizations

Comment: also woth noting the equivalent of the radius is known as the apothem.

Comment: @Chappers you should post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for any set in a metric space, the supremum of the distances between its points is also called the diameter. See, e.g. [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diameter#Generalizations).

Answer (score 1):

The [diameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diameter#Generalizations) keeps it name through geometric shapes, whereas the radius becomes known as the [apothem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apothem).

Answer (score 1):

This is an established meaning of the term in graph theory. Note that for an open region, "supremum" would technically be better than "maximum".